# React: Stop click event propagation when using mixed React and DOM events

Tags: css, reactjs, react-redux

We have a menu. If menu is open, We should be able to close it by clicking anywhere:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    document.addEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("click", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  openModal = () => {
    this.props.showModal();
  };

  handleClickOutside = ({ target }) => {
    const { displayMenu, toggleMenu, displayModal } = this.props;

    if (displayMenu) {
      if (displayModal || this.node.contains(target)) {
        return;
      }
      toggleMenu();
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <section ref={node => (this.node = node)}>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.openModal}>open modal</button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.openModal}>open modal</button>
        </p>
        <p>
          <button onClick={this.openModal}>open modal</button>
        </p>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

From menu, we can open a modal by clicking on button inside menu. We can close modal in two ways: by clicking close modal button inside modal, or on click on bakcdrop/overlay outside the modal:

```
class Modal extends Component {
  hideModal = () => {
    this.props.hideModal();
  };

  onOverlayClick = ({ target, currentTarget }) => {
    if (target === currentTarget) {
      this.hideModal();
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal-container" onClick={this.onOverlayClick}>
        <div className="modal">
          <button onClick={this.hideModal}>close modal</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And now, when menu and modal is open, on close modal click or modal overlay click I want to close only modal, menu should be still open. Only on second click (while modal is closed). At first glance it look pretty clear and easy, this condition should be responsible for that:

```
if (displayModal || this.node.contains(target)) {
  return;
}
```

If displayModal is `true`, nothing should happen. I'ts do not work, cause in my case, when you click at the close modal button or overlay, `hideModal` will be done faster than `toggleMenu`, and when we call `handleClickOutside` displayModal will already have `false`.

Full test case with open menu and modal at the start:

https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-rkso6

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is gonna be a bit longer, as I have investigated in similar issue recently. If you don't want to read everything, just have a look at the solutions.

#### Solutions

Two solutions come to my mind - the first is the easy fix, the second is cleaner, but requires an additional click handler component.

**1.) Easy fix**

In `Modal.js` `onOverlayClick`, add [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) like this:

```
  onOverlayClick = e => {
    // this is to stop click propagation in the react event system
    e.stopPropagation();
    // this is to stop click propagation to the native document click
    // listener in Menu.js
    e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
      this.hideModal();
    }
  };
```

On `document`, there are two click listener registered: a) the first is the top level listener of React b) your click listener in `Menu.js`. With `e.nativeEvent` you get the native DOM event wrapped by React. `stopImmediatePropagation` will cancel the second listener - and prevents closing of the menu, when you just want to close the modal. You can read more under explanation.

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-24415631-1-b189o)

**2.) The clean one**

With this solution, you can just use `event.stopPropagation`. All event handling (incl. the outside click handler) is done by React, so you don't have to use `document.addEventListener("click",...)` anymore. The `click-handler.js` down under will be just some proxy that catches all click events at the top level and forwards them in the React event system to your registered components.

Create `click-handler.jsx`:

```
import React from "react";

export const clickListenerApi = { addClickListener, removeClickListener };

export const ClickHandler = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div
      // span click handler over the whole viewport to catch all clicks
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
      onClick={e => {
        clickListeners.forEach(cb => cb(e));
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

// state of registered click listeners
let clickListeners = [];

function addClickListener(cb) {
  clickListeners.push(cb);
}

function removeClickListener(cb) {
  clickListeners = clickListeners.filter(l => l !== cb);
}
```

Menu.js:

```
class Menu extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    clickListenerApi.addClickListener(this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clickListenerApi.removeClickListener(this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  openModal = e => {
    // This click shall not close the menu,
    // so don't propagate the event to our clickListener API.
    e.stopPropagation();
    const { showModal } = this.props;
    showModal();
  };

  render() {... }
}
```

index.js:

```
const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ClickHandler>
      <Page />
    </ClickHandler>
  </Provider>
);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-57633984-2-hwyr8)

#### Explanation:

When you have both modal dialog and menu open and click *once* outside the modal, then with your current code the behavior is correct - both elements are closed. That is because in the DOM `document` has already received the click event and prepares itself to invoke your `handleClickOutside` click handler in `Menu`. So you have no chance anymore to cancel it via `e.stopPropagation()` in  `onOverlayClick` callback of `Modal`.

In order to understand the order of both firing click events, we have to comprehend that React has its own synthetic Event Handling system ([1](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html), [2](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)). The main point here is that React uses [top level event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and adds one single listener to `document` in the DOM for all event types.

Let's say you have a button `<button id="foo" onClick={...}>Click it</button>` somewhere in the DOM. When you click the button, it triggers a regular click event in the browser, that bubbles up to `document` and further until it reaches DOM root. React catches this click event with its single listener at `document`, and then internally traverses its virtual DOM again (similar to capture and bubble phase of the native DOM) and collects all relevant click callbacks that you have set with `onClick={...}` in your components. So your button `onClick` will be found and invoked later on.

Here is the interesting part: by the time React deals with the click events (which are now [synthetic React events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)), the native click event had already gone through the full capture/bubbling cycle in the DOM and doesn't exist in the native DOM anymore! That is the reason, why a mix of native click handlers (`document.addEventListener`) and React `onEvent` attributes in the components' JSX sometimes is so hard to handle and unpredictable. React event handlers should always be preferred.

Links to read on:

- [Understanding React's Synthetic Event System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327331/understanding-reacts-synthetic-event-system)  (also the linked [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-exactly-does-react-handles-events-71e8b5e359f2) with it)
- [ReactJS SyntheticEvent stopPropagation() only works with React events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24415631/reactjs-syntheticevent-stoppropagation-only-works-with-react-events)
- https://fortes.com/2018/react-and-dom-events/

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Damn, I was reading about  `stopImmediatePropagation` and trying to implementation into my issue, but sometimes I forget about React SyntheticEvent, and I was trying with jutst `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`. I also find a solution (better than timeout, but worse than your easy fix solution ;)), it's compare prevProps and props on componentDidUpdate and added/removed eventListener on props changing. Also huge thank's for clean one solution, it's a lot of new knowlege to me!

Comment: No problem. There's more than one way to skin a cat ;), choose what's most practical for you.

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38619981/react-prevent-event-bubbling-in-nested-components-on-click

Answer (score 0):

Call event.stopPropagation() inside your onOverlayClick() method and hideModal(), this will prevent the event to bubble up to the parent. Like this.

```
  onOverlayClick = e => {

    e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.target === e.currentTarget) {
      this.hideModal();
    }
  };
```

Comment: thanks, did you try this solution? Don't work for me. If I add stopPropagation to onOverlayClick, still two element close on overlay click.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry, @joseluismurillorios solution works as a quick workaround, but I recommend you really get around the execution order of your events :)

Comment: Sure, timeout is not a optimal solution, but which is? That's the reason why i'm here, I'm don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a little timeout to let the displayMenu variable updates:

```js
class Modal extends Component {
  hideModal = () => {
    const { hideModal } = this.props;
    setTimeout(() => {
      hideModal();
    }, 200); // Could work with 100ms
  };
  ...
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-u8262)

Comment: thanks, but setTimeout is a not perfect solution I guess.